# XPath not working in HtmlAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse this web page http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?site=glo&SearchText=watch&page=1 and get all the watches. However, i tried around dozen different XPaths with HTMLAgilityPack and I am able to scrape only 4 product links (should be around 36).

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36";
    var html = client.DownloadString(currentUrl);
    var document = new HtmlDocument();

    document.LoadHtml(html);

     var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']//a").Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value).Distinct();
```

I tried a lot of different XPaths, nothing seems to work, what is interesting even "//a[@href]" does not parse all the products but again i can see the links of only 4 of them.

I rechecked the html it's loading and i can see there more products. So what is the problem? Is it some HtmlAgilityPack issue? Could anybody help, I am struggling with this for three days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE*: I tested this against http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?site=glo&SearchText=watch&page=1

This is not a problem related to HTMLAgility pack nor with XPath. The issue here is that this website is using something called handlebar js to implement some type of lazy-loading.  One thing to keep in mind is that the `WebClient` is not a web browser.  That is, the `WebClient` retrieves the static HTML response that the server sends, and does not execute any javascript, whereas a browser would.

If you examine the raw HTML response that you're getting from the server, there are only four items in the `<ul class="util-clearfix son-list util-clearfix" id="hs-below-list-items">` element:

```
<ul class="util-clearfix son-list util-clearfix" id="hs-below-list-items">
    <!-- each li here is the ancestor of an anchor tag that you're hoping to scrape -->
    <li qrdata="200214047|32341478696|cn1513149702"  class="list-item list-item-first ">... </li>
    <li qrdata="200214047|32259964358|ali900189121"  class="list-item list-item-first ">...</li>
    <li qrdata="200214021|32388460600|cn1000737283"  class="list-item list-item-first ">..</li>
    <li qrdata="200214007|32400985609|cn1513217672"  class="list-item list-item-first ">...</li>
</ul>
```

After that, there's a script block where the remainder of the items reside:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="lazy-render" class="lazy-render">
    <li qrdata="200214007|32390805633|cn111508265"  class="list-item   ">
    ....
</script>
```

When you load the Raw HTML inside the `HtmlDocument` object, it treats the content inside the `<script>` element as `NodeType.Text`.  This is why you're not getting the results you want.

That said, here's a workaround:

```
var links = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='picRind history-item ']|//a[@class='picRind history-item j-p4plog']").Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value).Distinct();
foreach (var link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link);
}

var lazyContent = new HtmlDocument();
lazyContent.LoadHtml(document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script[@id='lazy-render']").First().ChildNodes[0].InnerHtml);
var lazyLinks = lazyContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='picRind history-item ']|//a[@class='picRind history-item j-p4plog']")
                .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
                .Distinct();

foreach (var link in lazyLinks)
{
    // Prints the remaining 36 product links
    Console.WriteLine(link);
}
```

What we did in the work-around was fetch the script block, and treated it as a new document, then scraped the remaining product links.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! However, i am still missing one link, i get 39 in total, lazylinks - 35, where is it possible to lose one?

Comment: I still retrieve 40 total.  Check whether there are subtle differences in the link that you're missing and the XPATH we've chosen (see that extra trailing space in the XPATH).  The XPATH I used is based on a common property shared amongst the links of interest. The properties on which you rely may be changed without the developer even intending for them to change.  It's not entirely improbable for the developer or their framework to remove that trailing space or change the way in which these "links" are rendered completely.

Answer (score -1):

Yahoo has new format, it causes errors while using HAP XPath.
For example HAP cannot parse data from Statistic Tab.
try this link: http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/key-statistics
to get Price/Book (mrq) data. HAP failed at parsing the ..section data.